# ui-btn-right not visible for the links in a listview

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have written an app that contains listviews. When I use the original css file:

```
href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css"
```

the listview shows the icon on the right side.

When I use the local copy (the app should be able to run without network connection) of the css file

```
href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" the icons are missing.
```

How can I make the icons visible again? Why are they hidden? I have added the following images to my project.

```
images/ajax-loader.gif
images/ajax-loader.png
images/icons-18-black.png
images/icons-18-white.png
images/icons-36-black.png 
images/icons-36-white.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please tell me where is your Image folder?
Is it in css folder?
If not then copy it to css folder Or change the css code as:

```
../images/icons-36-white.png
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution. I have moved the images folder into the the css folder. Is there a chance that I had come to the same idea alone. I have looked in the original zip file structure from jquerymobile and the images folder isn't part of the css folder.

Comment: @Thorben You are welcome. I am so happy that your problem have been solved. good luck dear :)